# VB.NET LumenWorks CsvReader Filtering and SqlBulkCopy

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, csv, filtering

I am currently handling large csv text files and using SqlBulkCopy to insert the contents into a single database. The requirement has now changed in that I must now filter the contents of the csv and bulk copy into multiple databases. I will try and keep the examples simple.

Example 1. requirement. Insert the rows from MyCSVFile1.txt where year = 2016 into Sql database 1 and where year = 2017 into Sql database 2. We would obviously have two connection strings for this etc. but you have the idea of what I am trying to do. Keep performance in mind as some files contain many columns with 10,000+ rows!

** Contents of MyCSVFile1.txt (Id, Date) ** Id is unique here.
"000012345", 2016-12-01 00:00:00
"000012346", 2016-12-15 00:00:00
"000012347", 2017-01-01 00:00:00
"000012348", 2017-01-15 00:00:00

```
' My current CsvReader / SqlBulkCopy with no filtering.
Using reader As New StreamReader("MyCSVFile1.txt")
    Dim csvReader As New CsvReader(reader, False)
    Dim copy As New SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(objConnection, SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, objSQLTransaction)
    copy.DestinationTableName = strTableName
    copy.WriteToServer(csvReader)
    objSQLTransaction.Commit()
End Using
```

Example 2. requirement. This one can get tricky. We need to keep two collections. Collection 1 having all of the Id's from MyCSVFile1.txt where year = 2016 and Collection 2 having all of the Id's where year = 2017. Insert the rows from MyCSVFile2.txt where the Id's exist in Collection 1 into Sql database 1 and where the Id's exist in Collection 2 into Sql database 2.

** Contents of MyCSVFile2.txt (Id, Item) ** Id is NOT unique here.
"000012345", "Item 350"
"000012345", "Item 420"
"000012345", "Item 124"
"000012346", "Item 798"
"000012348", "Item 425"
"000012348", "Item 877"

So, it is sort of like in Example 1 we would be adding a where clause and in Example 2 be adding an in operator. Any help would be appreciated! \m/ \m/

Comment: I have no idea of the capabilities of LumenWorks, but with CSVHelper you could read all the data as an IEnumerable; then use Where clauses to extract subsets for this or that criteria and send *that* off to the right DB. (today seems like world wide CSV day)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at the CSVHelper.